# A generalization of miracle flatness theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I wonder if the miracle flatness theorem [Generalizing miracle flatness (Matsumura 23.1) via finite Tor-dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7432/generalizing-miracle-flatness-matsumura-23-1-via-finite-tor-dimension)
still works if the rings involved are not local (and the dimension condition is deleted)?

In other words, is it true that $f: A \to B$, $A$ regular, $B$ Cohen-Macaulay,
implies that $f$ is flat? I guess the answer is no (maybe taking $A=k[x,y]$, $B=A/I$, with a right choice of an ideal $I$ of $A$ will serve as a counterexample? or maybe no).

But what if we further assume that: $f$ is injective, $A$ is Noetherian and $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module? Is $f$ flat in this case?

I ask this question since I have seen here this claim as a fact
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296971/what-has-projectiveness-to-do-with-cohen-macaulay-rings/297320#297320, with reference to EGA IV 6.1.5, though it seems (I do not know French) that Grothendieck talks about the local case.

Comment: Certainly there are counterexamples if you drop the dimension hypothesis, even with all of the other hypotheses you propose.  For instance, the ring homomorphism $k[x,y] \mapsto k[x,y/x]$ is a counterexample.

Comment: In my previous comment I missed the hypothesis that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.  Obviously this implies that the fibers are finite, hence zero-dimensional.  So the new hypothesis is simply replicating the "usual" hypothesis that the fiber dimension be constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your first question is obviously no, as you point out: the homomorphism $A\rightarrow A/I$ is essentially never flat. It is OK under your hypotheses ($f$ injective, $A$ noetherian, $B$ finitely generated) if you assume moreover that $B$ is a domain. A reference (in french, sorry) is Bourbaki, Algèbre Commutative X, §4, no. 3, Corollaire.

The hypothesis that $B$ is a domain is necessary for stupid reasons:  just take $B=A\times A/I$ with $A/I$ Cohen-Macaulay, again this is not flat over $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to read Bourbaki's Corollary.

Comment: Bourbaki's corollary even says that $B$ is a projective $A$-module. Precisely, if $A \subseteq B$, $A$ is regular, $B$ is a noetherian integral domain which is finitely generated as an $A$-module, then: $B$ is Macaulay iff $B$ is a projective $A$-module.

Comment: This is not stronger: a flat, finitely generated module over a noetherian ring is projective.

Comment: Yes, you are right (a regular ring is, by definition, noetherian). Actually, I now notice that in my question:

Comment: "But what if we further assume that...$A$ is noetherian", I should delete "$A$ is noetherian", since $A$ is already noetherian (since I have already mentioned the assumption that $A$ is regular).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on "the homomorphism $A \to A/I$ is essentialy never flat"; what exactly is your claim? maybe a relevant question is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208/can-a-quotient-ring-r-j-ever-be-flat-over-r

Comment: I guess you meant to use the following criterion for flatness http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562243/criterion-for-proving-flatness: If $R/I$ is $R$-flat, then in particulat $R/I \otimes_R I \to I(R/I)=0$ is injective, so the tensor product is zero, namely $I/I^2$ is zero, so $I=I^2$. Hence if we take an ideal $I$ such that $I \neq I^2$, then $R/I$ cannot be flat over $R$.

Comment: For example, in a noetherian integral domain $R$, if $I=I^2$, then $I=0$ or $I=R$, see Proposition 1.1 in http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-138-00/S0002-9947-1969-0238839-5/S0002-9947-1969-0238839-5.pdf